# How to specify a custom pull request template when creating a PR

Tags: github-api

I've created a custom pull request template (following [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository)) in a subfolder of the `.github` directory, e.g.:

```
├── PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE
│   └── custom-template.md
└── PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
```

[About automation for issues and pull requests with query parameters](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters) indicates you can pass the custom template name as a query parameter when creating the pull request, e.g.

> You can use the template query parameter to specify a template to automatically fill the issue or pull request body.

I've tried adding `"template": "custom-template.md"` as a query string when creating a [new pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request) but I end up with an empty pull request template. The default template in the `.github` directory still works as expected, but I can't figure out how to get the custom template to load via The API.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I also needed that to have localized templates.

Then I created the default one in `pt-BR`:

- `.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md`

Which will be used when creating a new Pull Request.

And the `en-US` one:

- `.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/PULL_REQUEST-en-US.md`

Than inside of the `pt-BR` I created a link to the second one:

- `[English (US)](?quick_pull=1&template=PULL_REQUEST-en-US.md)`

Assuming it will be accessed from the Pull Request page (`/compare/main...new-branch`) it will replace the query parameters.

---

*Reference:*

| Query parameter | Example |
| --- | --- |
| `template` | `https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/compare/main...my-branch?quick_pull=1&template=issue_template.md` creates a pull request with a template in the pull request body. The `template` query parameter works with templates stored in a `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE` subdirectory within the root, `docs/` or `.github/` directory in a repository. For more information, see "[Using templates to encourage useful issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests)." |

- https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/using-query-parameters-to-create-a-pull-request